# create slider with progress bar

Tags: javascript, slider, slick.js

I am creating a slider with timer pagination on dots, like https://www.samsung.com/africa_en/. I used pure Js instead of slick.js.  I need to make a progress bar stope with slider pause without Lage or delay ( progress not reset correctly ).

How can I stop pagination buttons with progress bars ?I

```
const slider = document.querySelector('.slider');
const slides = document.querySelector('.slides');
const slideImages = document.querySelectorAll('.slides img');
const pagination = document.querySelector('.pagination');
const playPauseBtn = document.querySelector('.play-pause'); // select the play/pause button

let slideIndex = 0;
let isPaused = false; // added variable to track pause state
const pausedDotAttribute = 'data-paused';

const prevBtn = document.querySelector('.prev');
const nextBtn = document.querySelector('.next');

// Set active dot
const dots = document.querySelectorAll('.dot');
dots[slideIndex].classList.add('active');

const progressContainer = document.querySelectorAll('.dot');
const progressBar = document.querySelectorAll('.progress-bar');
let isPausedd = false;
let progressWidth = 0;
let currentProgress = 0;

function startProgress() {
  let timerId = setInterval(() => {
    if (!isPausedd) {
      progressWidth++;
      if (progressWidth >= 100) {
        progressWidth = 0;
        progressBar[currentProgress].style.width = `${progressWidth}%`;
        clearInterval(timerId);
        currentProgress++;
        if (currentProgress >= progressBar.length) {
          currentProgress = 0;
        }
        startProgress();
      } else {
        progressBar[currentProgress].style.width = `${progressWidth}%`;
      }
    }
  }, 50);

  progressContainer[currentProgress].addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
    isPausedd = true;
  });

  progressContainer[currentProgress].addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    isPausedd = false;
  });
}

startProgress();


// --------------------------------------------

// Set timer
let timerId = setInterval(() => {
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex >= slideImages.length) {
    slideIndex = 0;
  }
  showSlide();
}, 5000);

// Show slide function
function showSlide() {
  slides.style.transform = `translateX(-${slideIndex * 100 / slideImages.length}%)`;
  dots.forEach(dot => dot.classList.remove('active'));
  dots[slideIndex].classList.add('active');
  if (isPaused) {
    dots[slideIndex].classList.add('paused'); // add paused class to active dot when paused
   } else {
    dots[slideIndex].classList.remove('paused'); // remove paused class when resumed
   }
}


// Toggle play/pause button and stop/restart timer
playPauseBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (playPauseBtn.textContent === 'Pause') {
    clearInterval(timerId);
    playPauseBtn.textContent = 'Play';
  } else {
    timerId = setInterval(() => {
      slideIndex++;
      if (slideIndex >= slideImages.length) {
        slideIndex = 0;
      }
      showSlide();
    }, 5000);
    playPauseBtn.textContent = 'Pause';
  }
});

 // Pause slider on slide hover
slides.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
clearInterval(timerId);
  playPauseBtn.textContent = 'Play';
    isPaused = true;
  dots[slideIndex].setAttribute(pausedDotAttribute, isPaused);   // ?
});

// Resume slider on slide mouse leave
slides.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  isPaused = false;
   timerId = setInterval(() => {
      slideIndex++;
      if (slideIndex >= slideImages.length) {
        slideIndex = 0;
      }
      showSlide();
    }, 5000);
 playPauseBtn.textContent = 'Pause';
});


 // Navigate to previous slide
prevBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  slideIndex--;
  if (slideIndex < 0) {
    slideIndex = slideImages.length - 1;
  }
  showSlide();
});

// Navigate to next slide
nextBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex >= slideImages.length) {
    slideIndex = 0;
  }
  showSlide();
});
```

```
<!-- HTML code -->
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slides">
    <img
      src="https://online.marvansmobile.com/assets_2/images/demos/demo1/slides/slide1.jpg"
    />
    <img
      src="https://jssors8.azureedge.net/demos/image-slider/img/px-bloom-blossom-flora-65219-image.jpg"
    />
    <img
      src="https://jssors8.azureedge.net/demos/image-slider/img/px-action-athlete-athletes-848618-image.jpg"
    />
  </div>
  <div class="pagination">
    <div class="dot active" data-index="0">
      <div class="progress-bar"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="dot" data-index="1">
      <div class="progress-bar"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="dot" data-index="2">
      <div class="progress-bar"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="prev">&#10094;</button>
<button class="next">&#10095;</button>

<button class="play-pause">Pause</button>

<style>
  /* CSS code */
  .slider {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .slides {
    display: flex;
    width: 300%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: transform 0.5s ease;
  }
  .slides img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .pagination {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    display: flex;
  }
  .dot {
    width: 300px;
    height: 5px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    /* border-radius: 50%; */
    background-color: gray;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .dot.active {
    background-color: black;
  }
  .dot.active::after {
    content: '';
    background-color: cyan;
    height: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    /* right: 0; */
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    animation: progress;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  }
  .dot.active.paused::after {
    animation-play-state: paused; /* added property */
  }

  @keyframes progressj {
    0% {
      width: 0;
    }
    100% {
      width: 300px;
    }
  }
  .prev,
  .next {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    background: transparent;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 24px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .prev {
    left: 0;
  }
  .next {
    right: 0;
  }
  .dot {
        width: 300px;
        height: 10px;
        background-color: black;
      }
      .progress-bar {
        width: 0%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: red;
        transition: width 1s linear;
      }
</style>
```

I am creating a slider with timer pagination on dots, like https://www.samsung.com/africa_en/. I used pure Js instead of slick.js.  I need to make a progress bar stope with slider pause without Lage or delay ( progress not reset correctly ).

How can I stop pagination buttons with progress bars ?I